# Write a MessageDirect using the xxhash algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

I would be grateful for help with the following problem.

An application I'm working on uses the SHA-256 algorithm to produce a hashing value.  i.e.

```
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
```

This has given us performance issues, and so I have been asked to replace this with an xxhash function.  (Our main concern is having a good and fast hashing algorithm.)

We have identified the following component which we understand to be a good and effective implementation.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4/1.0.0

An example is given here for how to use the artefact.  https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java

```
XXHashFactory factory = XXHashFactory.fastestInstance();

byte[] data = "12345345234572".getBytes("UTF-8");
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

int seed = 0x9747b28c; // used to initialize the hash value, use whatever
                   // value you want, but always the same
StreamingXXHash32 hash32 = factory.newStreamingHash32(seed);
byte[] buf = new byte[8]; // for real-world usage, use a larger buffer, like 8192 bytes
for (;;) {
  int read = in.read(buf);
  if (read == -1) {
    break;
  }
  hash32.update(buf, 0, read);
}
int hash = hash32.getValue();
```

In order to switch-out the SHA-256 MessageDigest, I think the best course of action is to extend the java.security.MessageDigest abstract class.  The following shows what I think would be an appropriate implementation, with missing implementation for engineDigest().  Would anyone be able to give guidance on how to implement this method, or point out an approach which they think is better?  Thanks in advance.

```
package com.company.functions.crypto;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.jpountz.xxhash.StreamingXXHash32;
import net.jpountz.xxhash.XXHashFactory;

public class XxHashMessageDigest extends MessageDigest {

public static final String XXHASH = "xxhash";
private static final int SEED = 0x9747b28c;
private static final XXHashFactory FACTORY = XXHashFactory
        .fastestInstance();
private List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

protected XxHashMessageDigest() {
    super(XXHASH);
}

@Override
protected void engineUpdate(byte input) {
    // intentionally no implementation
}

@Override
protected void engineUpdate(byte[] input, int offset, int len) {

    StreamingXXHash32 hash32 = FACTORY.newStreamingHash32(SEED);
    hash32.update(input, offset, len);
    values.add(hash32.getValue());
}

@Override
protected byte[] engineDigest() {

    /*
     * TODO provide implementation to "digest" the list of values into a
     * hash value
     */

    engineReset();

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void engineReset() {
    values.clear();
}

}
```